Yellowstone geyser multi connection latency
I’m connecting my client to solana via geyser port on my rpc.
I have noticed, that I get 1-1.5 second delay of account updates, when I do approximately 90 different subscriptions, comparing to account updates with only 1 subscription.
Kindly help to understand why does increasing different subscriptions number create a delay of the accountupdates .
This is current config:
{
    "libpath": "libyellowstone_grpc_geyser.so",
    "log": {
        "level": "info"
    },
    "grpc": {
        "address": "0.0.0.0:11000",
        "max_decoding_message_size": "4_194_304",
        "snapshot_plugin_channel_capacity": null,
        "snapshot_client_channel_capacity": "50_000_000",
        "channel_capacity": "100_000",
        "unary_concurrency_limit": 100,
        "unary_disabled": false,
        "filters": {
            "accounts": {
                "max": 100,
                "any": false,
                "account_max": 10,
                "account_reject": ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"],
                "owner_max": 10,
                "owner_reject": ["11111111111111111111111111111111"]
            },
            "slots": {
                "max": 1
            },
            "transactions": {
                "max": 1,
                "any": false,
                "account_include_max": 10,
                "account_include_reject": ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"],
                "account_exclude_max": 10,
                "account_required_max": 10
            },
            "transactions_status": {
                "max": 1,
                "any": false,
                "account_include_max": 10,
                "account_include_reject": ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"],
                "account_exclude_max": 10,
                "account_required_max": 10
            },
            "blocks": {
                "max": 1,
                "account_include_max": 10,
                "account_include_any": false,
                "account_include_reject": ["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"],
                "include_transactions": true,
                "include_accounts" : false,
                "include_entries" : false
            },
            "blocks_meta": {
                "max": 1
            },
            "entry": {
                "max": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "prometheus": {
        "address": "0.0.0.0:8999"
    },
    "block_fail_action": "log"
}


You're probably better off asking the yellowstone devs directly https://github.com/rpcpool/yellowstone-grpc/
